# CircleCi 2.0 working with project inside the subdirectory

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I am trying to integrate my `springboot` tutorial project with CircleCi.

My project is inside a subdirectory inside a Github repository and I get the following error from CircleCi.

> Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this
>   directory (/home/circleci/recipe). Please verify you invoked Maven
>   from the correct directory.

I can't figure out how to tell circle-ci my project is inside a subdirectory. I have tried a couple of things, as well as trying to `cd` inside 'recipe' but it does not work or even feel right.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
Spring-tutorials
 |
 +-- projectA
 |    
 +-- recipe
 |   | +--pom.xml
```

Here is my `config.yml`

```yaml
# Java Maven CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/recipe

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: cd recipe/; ls -la; pwd;

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - recipe-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - recipe-

      - run: cd recipe; mvn dependency:go-offline

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/recipe/.m2
          key: recipe-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: mvn integration-test
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. I believe the combination of

```yaml
    working_directory: ~/spring-tutorial/recipe
```

and of

```yaml
  - checkout:
      path: ~/spring-tutorial
```

made it work.

Here is my working `config.yml`:

```yaml
# Java Maven CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/spring-tutorial/recipe
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/spring-tutorial

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - recipe-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - recipe-

      - run: mvn dependency:go-offline

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: recipe-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: mvn integration-test
```

Comment: Why does this work? Doesn't working_Directory set the working_directory? Why do we have to checkout also to the folder before the sub_directory?

Comment: According to the documentation of [circleci for working_directory](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#executors-requires-version-21): `In which directory to run the steps.`

And [checkout](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#checkout) is checking out the source code from a git repository.

Comment: This setup gives me Directory (/home/circleci/spring-tutorial) you are trying to checkout to is not empty and not a git repository. That's because recipe folder exists in spring-tutorial

Comment: @Ville in my case spring-tutorial was a git repository

Comment: Same. But as you define working_directory: ~/spring-tutorial/recipe, spring-tutorial already has a folder (recipe) so you cannot checkout there since it is not empty, right?

Comment: I run into the same issue "is not empty and not a git repository". It seems specifying `working_directory: ~/spring-tutorial/recipe` creates both directories, causing the checkout to fail because `recipe` already exists.

Answer (score 18):

I got confused a little bit so I would like to clarify it more

the key solution for building subdirectory to define your working-space, in this case, its subfolder so it will defined like this

```
 working_directory: ~/repo/sub_folder
```

and checkout to

```
- checkout:
     path: ~/repo
```

to be like this

```
# Javascript Node CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:7.10

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4

    working_directory: ~/repo/sub_folder

    steps:
      - checkout:
            path: ~/repo

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run: npm install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: npm test
```

Answer (score 5):

If anyone tries running npm command and `cd` is not working as expected, i.e like:

```
cd subdir && npm run command
```

You can use `--prefix` option of npm.

```
- run:
      name: Run start command in recipe folder
      command: npm --prefix ./recipe run start

# then in same file
- run:
      name: Run test command in app folder
      command: npm --prefix ./app run test
```

Comment: I don't use npm as it is not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

My codebase has a `web` directory under which the entire web application resides including the `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, Webpack config etc. My application has to be built inside the `web` directory and served from the `dist` that gets created under it. I wanted CircleCI to run tests inside this `web` subdirectory after installing the required dependencies in it. The accepted answer did not work for me in CircleCI 2.1 Config. This is the `config.yml` I tried

```yml
version: 2.1

jobs:
  test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:16.15.1

    # Added working directory pointing to `web`
    working_directory: ~/app/web

    steps:
      - checkout:
          # Checking out to the parent directory
          path: ~/app

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - npm-packages-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
            - npm-packages-

      - run:
          name: Installing packages
          command: npm install

      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: npm run test

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: npm-packages-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
```

It gave me the error

```
Directory you are trying to checkout to is not empty and not a git repository
```

What finally worked for me was by making use of the [`working_directory`](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#run) property supported by the `run` step. The updated CI config is as given below.

```yml
version: 2.1

jobs:
  test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:16.15.1

    # Kept the working directory as such
    working_directory: ~/app

    steps:
      # Kept checkout as such
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            # Restoring cache using web/package-lock.json
            - npm-packages-{{ checksum "web/package-lock.json" }}
            - npm-packages-

      # Running npm install in the web directory using working_directory
      # property of the run step
      - run:
          name: Installing packages
          working_directory: ~/app/web
          command: npm install

      # Running npm test in the web directory using working_directory
      # property of the run step
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          working_directory: ~/app/web
          command: npm test

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          # Saving cache using web/package-lock.json
          key: npm-packages-{{ checksum "web/package-lock.json" }}
```