# CircleCI Rust Tests in a species subdirectory

Tags: rust, integration-testing, circleci

I am trying to set up CircleCI for my project. My project structure is as follows:

```
.circleci
  +- config.yml
tables
  +- src
  +- target
  +- tests
  +- Cargo.lock
  +- Cargo.toml
core
  +- (...) (regular rust project)
derive
  +- (...) (regular rust project)
(...) (some other directories and files)
```

My `config.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/simple_tables/tables
    docker:
      - image: cimg/rust:1.50.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: cargo --version
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: "cargo test"
```

I got this from [the CircleCI blog](https://circleci.com/blog/rust-ci/). The `working_directory` I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570221/circleci-2-0-working-with-project-inside-the-subdirectory).

When this runs, I get the following output however:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
cargo test
error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/home/circleci/simple_tables/tables` or any parent directory

Exited with code exit status 101
CircleCI received exit code 101
```

How can I run the tests located in the `/tables/tests`?

Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Comment: If you read the answers to the question you linked carefully, it seems that the `checkout` is applied after the `working_directory`, so your tables directory is now in fact at `~/simple_tables/tables/tables`. (add a `- run: find .` to verify). The answers you linked also explain how to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for the `- run: find .` tip! I managed to solve the problem

Comment: A short comment (or a self-answer) on how you solved it would probably be appreciated, if anyone ever comes here from a search engine. (Also, I should have recommended `- run: find "$PWD"`. Oh well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Caesar mentioned, you can use `- run: find "$PWD"` for debugging.

Also make sure that you have

```yaml
- checkout:
     path: ~/repo
```

instead of just `- checkout`

I also had to update `- image: cimg/rust:1.50.0` to `- image: cimg/rust:1.56.0`, because the `1.56.0` indicates the rust version and as of now, this is the latest rust version (you can run `rust --version` on your own computer to get your installed version).